# menu and banner having jQuery.easing clash

Tags: javascript, jquery

`http://open-pages.com/Alpinemadotcom/`

The menu and slide banner has a clash I think.

Below before `</body>` there are two scripts for each menu and banner and they use same or different jquery version.

If  I use `either` or `both` versions. the menu do not work properly or the banner do not work with clicks and no fade in outs or slides (abrupt image change).

What can be wrong?

**Udate --------**

I found, after quite hit and tries, that `jquery.easing.js` is causing problems for banner and if excluded. the menu dont work. `jquery.easing.compatibility.js` dont solve problems either. I suspect `jquery.min` (which is actuall `v1.3.2`) is also cauting problems.

Any solution?

Comment: You cannot use 2 different jquery versions! Try rewrite one of the plugins to the other jquery version

Comment: rewritting is very difficult for a newbie like me. any other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not surprised you are having trouble if you try to use both libraries, that's just asking for trouble.

It would seem though that the Nivo slider you're using does not like the newer version of jQuery. You don't seem to be doing anything very special with that plugin though, so you might have better luck using the jQuery cycle plugin instead? I've used it a lot on different websites and it has a lot of great features, very easy to implement too and works with the version of jQuery you're using on your menu.

Comment: I see, Can you please give some working and compatible things you have already use? or .. finally what do you suggest? which version (one and one only) to use for both menu and slider to work?

Comment: see update -I found, after quite hit and tries, that jquery.easing.js is causing problems for banner and if excluded. the menu dont work.  jquery.easing.compatibility.js dont solve problems either.    I suspect jquery.min  (which is actuall v1.3.2) is also cauting problems.